# How to subclass Python list without type problems?

Tags: python, list, subclass

I want to implement a custom list class in Python as a subclass of `list`. What is the minimal set of methods I need to override from the base `list` class in order to get full type compatibility for all list operations?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235556/python-subclass-builtin-list) suggest that at least `__getslice__` needs to be overridden. From further research, also `__add__` and `__mul__` will be required. So I have this code:

```
class CustomList(list):
    def __getslice__(self,i,j):
        return CustomList(list.__getslice__(self, i, j))
    def __add__(self,other):
        return CustomList(list.__add__(self,other))
    def __mul__(self,other):
        return CustomList(list.__mul__(self,other))
```

The following statements work as desired, even without the overriding methods:

```
l = CustomList((1,2,3))
l.append(4)                       
l[0] = -1
l[0:2] = CustomList((10,11))    # type(l) is CustomList
```

These statements work only with the overriding methods in the above class definition:

```
l3 = l + CustomList((4,5,6))    # type(l3) is CustomList
l4 = 3*l                        # type(l4) is CustomList
l5 = l[0:2]                     # type(l5) is CustomList
```

The only thing I don't know how to achieve is making extended slicing return the right type:

```
l6 = l[0:2:2]                   # type(l6) is list
```

What do I need to add to my class definition in order to get `CustomList` as type of `l6`?

Also, are there other list operations other than extended slicing, where the result will be of `list` type instead of `CustomList`?

Comment: "I want to implement a custom list class in Python as a subclass of list". **Why**?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: `CustomList` is intended to hold data of a specific type, and will have additional parameters and methods applying to these data (which I left out for the question).

Comment: Silvado, just out of curiosity, can you please give more information on CustomList and some details about the data? Inheriting from base types in Python is a VERY unappreciated practice, so maybe there is a way to do what you want to do without inheriting from list.

Comment: BasicWOlf: Why is subclassing from base types unappreciated?

Comment: Because built-in types are optimized to work as they are. You can never assume what will be the result of overriding *some* of the methods and leaving other methods intact. -- Subclassing built-in types is a very common behaviour of people with Ruby background. DON'T do that in Python.

Comment: @BasicWolf: Each CustomList is intended to hold information about one experiment, and the elements will represent data about individual objects measured during one experiment. The additional parameters for CustomList are information about the experiment (thus applying to all measured objects).

Comment: @Silvado, then why not create `class Experiment` with two fields: `mesures` (list) and `information` (whatever it is)? The whole issue looks like you're trying to build a house starting with a roof.

Comment: @BasicWolf: that's how I had it so far, but found it inconvenient to always write `datalist.items[i]` or `for d in datalist.items` when accessing individual items, and wanted to try a different way. But I think I will follow your advice and not subclass `list`. As far as I understand, I can still implement `__getitem__` and the other methods, just operating on a normal list `self.items` instead of on `self`, to have list-like functionality like I want.

Comment: Absolutely right. Or just `items = datalist.items` :)

Comment: I want to subclass `list` to provide a custom class that can be used as an iterable without having to implement that again. Seems like an ideal scenario for subclassing a built-in class to me, and totally Pythonic. I will over-ride some methods and add more, but with many `list` mthods unused. Every time I start using a super class method I'll check whether it works and if I have to over-ride it. What can be wrong with that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Firstly, I recommend you follow [Björn Pollex's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180014/how-to-subclass-python-list-without-type-problems/8180073#8180073) (+1).

To get past this particular problem (`type(l2 + l3) == CustomList`), you need to implement a custom [`__add__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__):

```
   def __add__(self, rhs):
        return CustomList(list.__add__(self, rhs))
```

And for [extended slicing](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html):

```
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        result = list.__getitem__(self, item)
        try:
            return CustomList(result)
        except TypeError:
            return result
```

I also recommend...

```
pydoc list
```

...at your command prompt. You'll see which methods [`list`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) exposes and this will give you a good indication as to which ones you need to override.

Comment: Thanks. With the second hint, I saw all non-underscore methods for list (e.g. `extend`) etc.. I haven't tried all of them, but since these all act in place, I wouldn't expect any type problems there. So only extended slicing seems to remain as my problem...

Comment: This implementation of `__getitem__` raises TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable on either `l[0]` or `l[0:2:2]`. So I guess I need to distinguish at least whether `item` is a slice or individual index.

Comment: I suggested an edit of the answer in this direction which seems to work.

Comment: Great, this works as expected. Just out of curiosity, what about implementation efficiency if I access mostly single items aka `l[0]`? In this case, I will always run into the exception handling code.

Comment: I'm following the Python [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) idiom. [Premature optimization...](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) and all that...

Answer (score 27):

You should probably read these two sections from the documentation:

- [Emulating container types](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types)
- [Additional methods for emulating sequence types](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#additional-methods-for-emulation-of-sequence-types) (Python 2 only)

**Edit:** In order to handle extended slicing, you should make your `__getitem__`-method handle slice-objects (see [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), a little further down).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. So I learnt that multiplication and extended slicing is also an issue. I extended my code to get addition and multiplication right (see edit), but am still stuck with extended slicing.

Comment: The second link is broken.

Comment: Indeed, this section doesn't seem to exist in the Python 3 documentation, so it's now pointing at the Python 2 docs.

Answer (score 8):

Possible cut-the-gordian-knot solution: subclass UserList instead of list. (Worked for me.) That is what UserList is there for.

Comment: This is by far the easiest and least error-prone solution for my use-case. Checkout the docs for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList

Answer (score 0):

As a slight modification to Johnsywebs answer. I would only convert to a CustomList if item is a slice. Otherwise CustomList(["ab"])[0] would give you CustomList(["a", "b"]) which is not what you want. Like this:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    result = list.__getitem__(self, item)
    if type(item) is slice:
        return CustomList(result)
    else:
        return result
```