# Looking for OOP Pythonic approach for putting objects in a 'list object' as opposed to just using [list]

Tags: python, class, oop

For some reason I cannot conceptualize how to use Checkbook.class object instead of "ledger [list]"  Trying to keep my approach OOP.  What is a best practices approach to the objectives of this code?  (Yes, I have other "newbie" questions too, but I would be happy just to get some input on this.)

```
import sys
import time

transNum=0
ledger = []
debitInput=['Check Number: ', 'Transaction Date: ',
            'Payee: ', 'Amount: ', 'Memo (or Enter to skip): ']
creditInput=['Check Number: ', 'Transaction Date: ',
            'Source: ', 'Amount: ', 'Memo (or Enter to skip): ']

# a Payee is a persistent record/lookup of current, past and new payees
class Payee:
    pass

# a Source is a persistent record/lookup of current, past and new sources
class Source:
    pass


# a Checkbook is a collection of Transaction objects upon which queries may be performed
class Checkbook:
    def __init__(self, newTrans):
        pass

# a Transaction is a collection of Debit and Credit objects
class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, chkNum, transDate, thirdParty, amount, memo=''):
        self.chkNum = chkNum
        self.transDate = transDate
        self.memo=memo
        self.thirdParty=thirdParty
        self.amount=amount
        self.transNum = transNum



class Debit(Transaction):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Transaction.__init__(self, *args)
        self.payee=self.thirdParty
        del self.thirdParty
        self.amount=int(self.amount)*-1


class Credit(Transaction):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Transaction.__init__(self, *args)
        self.source=self.thirdParty
        del self.thirdParty
        self.amount=int(self.amount)


while True:
    transact = []
    transNum += 1
    choice=input('Posting debit [d], credit [c] or [x] to exit: ')
    if choice == 'x': break
    elif choice == 'd':
        for field in debitInput:
            field = input(field)
            transact.append(field)
        trans = Debit(transact[0], transact[1], transact[2], transact[3], transact[4])
        ledger.append(trans)


    elif choice == 'c':
        for field in creditInput:
            field = input(field)
            transact.append(field)
        trans = Credit(transact[0], transact[1], transact[2], transact[3], transact[4])
```

Comment: OOP lists are pointless. Lists do not make useful class objects; they are glue for holding objects together. A class object can hold a list of other object (via just a plain non-oop list that it hides inside). It's not useful to have a class object just to hold a list of other objects; there is a reason why it holds a list of other objects. They are perhaps registered listeners and the object delivers notifications to them, or some such thing.   It does make sense to have some degree of polymorphism between different kinds of lists, but that doesn't require the use of an object system.

Comment: @Kaz that's very true, but I get the idea that the OP was assigned this as homework.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback.  Its not homework but it is my first stab at something from scratch after going through the Lutz books.  I like the list for traversing and querying the data but I just felt like I was missing something by going straight to the built-in list objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Checkbook:

    def __init__(self):
        self.transactions = []    # Checkbook is just a wrapper around a list

    def __getitem__(self, index): # implementing [x]
        return self.transactions[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, transaction): #implementing [x] = i
        self.transactions[index] = transaction

    def append(self, transaction): # implementing .append(x)
        self.transactions.append(transaction)

    def extend(self, transaction_list): # implementing .extend([x,y,z])
        self.transactions.extend(transaction_list)

    # and so on for every method which you want to support
```

Or you can [subclass `list`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180014/how-to-subclass-python-list-without-type-problems).

Is this for homework? It's silly to assign this in Python. [You'd never really want to subclass `list`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180014/how-to-subclass-python-list-without-type-problems#comment10047774_8180014). I had a better exercise in university in which I had to re-implement a `std::vector` using templates, a dynamic array (with `malloc()`), and operator overloading... what fun! The `std::map` exercise was even better :)