# Python method that can be called on a list of objects

Tags: python, oop, syntax

When a method is called on an object in python as:

```
obj.func()
```

then python passes the `obj` as the first argument to the `func()`. I want to do something like:

```
[obj1, obj2].func()
```

and have it processed as:

```
[obj1.func(), obj.func()]
```

Is there a way of defining this kind of methods in python?

Comment: `map()` may help you I guess

Comment: `[x.func() for x in [obj1, obj2]]`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The only way to do exactly what you're asking for is to subclass python build-in class `list`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180014/how-to-subclass-python-list-without-type-problems) should help.

PS: it is a really bad thing to do that though.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a **list comprehension**, you get basically what you need:

```
[obj.func() for obj in [obj1, obj2]]
```

This is standard syntax and is easy to understand for other Python programmers.