# Add a method to a Built-In Function

Tags: python, arrays, class, methods, built-in

How can I add a method to a built-in function?

For example:

Adding push function (Inspired from `deque` module) to a list

```
def push(self, element):
    self.insert(0, self)  # First way I could think of

# And adding push to built-in `list`
# Example:

class list:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        # Do something with iterable
        self.push = push
```

Not necessarily `push` method but add **any** *method* to **any** *built-in function*.
I'm just giving an example.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Also, technically `list` is not a function; it's a type which is callable.

Comment: I thought `list` was just a class which uses the assembly level language

Comment: Well, classes aren't functions, either; they're also callable objects. (I don't want to get into the difference between types and classes, here; in Python 2 they are minor and in Python 3 there is no difference. There *are* differences between built-in functions/types and user-defined functions/types, one of which being the built-in ones are more-or-less immutable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fully general answer is that you can't. The built-in stuff is implemented at a lower level than normal classes, so you get a little less freedom for monkey-patching and such.

Depending on what specifically you're after, there can be workarounds though. For example, if you want a list with some extra methods, you can just [subclass it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180014/how-to-subclass-python-list-without-type-problems)