# Python add custom function to datatypes

Tags: python, class, oop, types

I want to add a function or a class which I can directly call from an integer such as:

```
1.customFunction(parameters)
36.customFunctionTwo(onearg, twoarg)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: As explained in this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52337026/13433648), you need to subclass the Integer class as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5604772/13433648).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python won't let you redefine an int type, but using a dictionary you can do it:

```py
class One:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def Custom(self,parameter1,parameter2):
    print(parameter1,parameter2)

dic={1:One()}

dic[1].Custom("Parameter 1","Parameter 2")
```

Then you just do it again for each number.