# Treat a single element list as a scalar in Python

Tags: python, list, subclass

¿Is it possible to define a subclass of a python list which allow the use of single-element list variables as if they were scalars?

For example I would like to be able to do:

```
class CustomList(list):
    ...
    ...

list1 = CustomList([2])
list2 = CustomList([3])
list3 = CustomList([4,5,6])
list4 = CustomList([{'foo':'bar'}])
list1 #should return list1[0]
list4['foo'] #should return list4[0]['foo'] = 'bar'
list1 + list2 #should return list1[0] + list2[0] = 5
```

but keeping the ability to use the list as normal:

```
for i in list3:
    print list[i]
```

Comment: What do you hope the addition method does? Concatenation like for a list?

Comment: Defining a ``class CustomList(list)`` is *exactly* what is needed, what problem did you encounter?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "list1 + list2" should return the sum of the values of list1[0] and list2[0]. See my last edit.

Comment: I see what you want, but not what your problem is. Do you not know how to overload operators? How to switch depending on the length of lists? How to use the base class behaviour for non-scalar lists?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I do not have experience defining classes but I can adapt Green Cloak Guy example for other binary operators. However I do not know what method to redefine (or what operator to overload) to use for example "print(list)" instead of "print(list[0])".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you would effectively need to override any methods you'd want it to work with.

When you call certain operators on objects like lists, you end up calling hidden methods on those objects. In the example you gave, `result = list1 + list2`, the function that is actually called is `list1.__add__(list2)`. You can subclass `list` and override these methods, if you want. For example:

```
class CustomList(list):
    def __add__(self, value):
        if len(self) == 1 and len(value) == 1:
            return self[0] + value[0]
        else:
            return CustomList(list.__add__(self, value))
```

will treat `list1` and `list2` as scalars if they're both of length 1, and refer to the normal `list` functionality otherwise. [This stackoverflow answer on subclassing `list`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180014/how-to-subclass-python-list-without-type-problems/8180073#8180073) might be helpful to you.

---

To address your edit, a more general solution would be fairly simple - instead of overriding the `__add__()` function, try overriding `__getitem__()`, which is called whenever you use the square-bracket operators:

```
class CustomList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, y):
        if len(self) == 1:
            return self[0][y]
        else:
            return self[y]
```

This might cause problems when trying to concatenate arrays, however; `list3 + list1` would cause an error because `list1` was not an iterable, though of course you could override `__add__` to simply add the second value as a list element if the list was more than one element long.

---

Console output using the above declaration:

```
>>> list1 = CustomList([2])
>>> list2 = CustomList([3])
>>> list3 = CustomList([4,5,6])
>>> print(list1 + list2)
5
>>> print(list2 + list3)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Addition should probably return another ``CustomList``, not a plain ``list``.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want to do with arithmetic operators, but still, I do not have idea of what to with something like: list4 = "CustomList[{'foo':'bar'}]" and then do "print(list4['foo'])" instead of "print(list4[0]['foo'])". See my edit.

Comment: If you wanted to make that work like a dictionary, then you could also override the `__getitem__()` method, which activates whenever you use the square-bracket operators. I edited a simple example into my post, though of course you should do whatever you need to make it fit your implementation

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Great! I think I can work with your last example. List concatenation is not an issue because I'm not going to use the subclass as replacement of the standard list class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by adding two classes you meant concatenating two lists, you could do something like this (notice the __add__ method to see how to addition works):

```
from collections import MutableSequence

class CustomList(MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, data=[]):
        self._list = data 

    def __add__(self, newlist):
        return self._list + newlist._list

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._list)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self._list[i]

    def __delitem__(self, i):
        del self._list[i]

    def __setitem__(self, i, val):
        self._list[i] = val

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._list)

    def insert(self, i, val):
        self._list.insert(i, val)
```

Comment: ``list`` can be subclassed directly, there is no need to write all that boilerplate.