# Is it possible to give a list a class attribute?

Tags: python

Let’s say I have a nested list of various details about people is it possible that if the first element in a list start with a certain letter to give the list an attribute that is that letter

For example if I have the list

list_ex= [[mary, 18, nyc], [jake, 19, la],
[mason, 20, Arizona]]

I also have the classes

```
class first:
    def __init__(self): 
        self._letter = None 
    def letter(self): 
        return self._letter 

class find_first:
     def example(self):
         details = list_ex
         for detail range(len(details)):
            if details[detail][0][0] == “m”:
                details[detail]._letter = “m” 

            else:
                details._letter=“NONE”
```

i get the error that a list can’t have this attribute is there a way to fix this or is it’s just not possible

Comment: Why do you want to structure the data like that? Why not model the things in your list with data classes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html?

Comment: I haven’t really learned how to work with those so this was just a question I had if its possible to do with just classes

Comment: You are allowed to [subclass `list`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180014/how-to-subclass-python-list-without-type-problems) to add functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As @ndc85430 said, dataclasses would be easier to use, but if you want to use regular classes, you can do it this way:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, age, state):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.state = state

    def get_first_letter(self):
        return self.name[0]

items = [
    Item('mary', 18, 'nyc'),
    Item('jake', 19, 'la'),
    Item('mason', 20, 'Arizona'),
]
for item in items:
    if item.name.get_first_letter() == 'm':
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```