# Add extension to List of enums

Tags: python, list, enums, extension-methods, built-in

I have an array of enums and would like a convenient method to access the enum string representation directly.

As an example. I have the following enum

```
from enum import Enum

class Countries(Enum):
    CH = "Switzerland"
    DE = "Germany"
    FR = "France"

sel_countries = [Countries.CH, Countries.FR]
```

And now, I would like to have a method like `[Countries.CH, Countries.FR].toString()` that returns `['Switzerland', 'France']`.

I know, I could get the desired results using `[e.value for e in sel_countries]`.

But how could I add such a method to a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add methods to builtins, the easiest way is to create a new subclass. [When subclassing containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8180014/14536215) such as `list` and `dict` it's best to use `UserList` and `UserDict` instead.

```py
from enum import Enum
from collections import UserList

class Countries(Enum):
    CH = "Switzerland"
    DE = "Germany"
    FR = "France"

class EnumList(UserList):
    def to_string(self):
        return EnumList([item.value for item in self])

sel_countries = EnumList([Countries.CH, Countries.FR])

print(sel_countries.to_string())
```